# GitHub pages URL pointing to GitHub username instead the repository name

Tags: github, url, jekyll, github-pages

This GitHub pages application is written in `Jekyll`. I want it to go live from `https://indrajith.github.io`. But it goes live from a different domain and starts with my GitHub profile username.

[image]

I referred [GitHub pages documentation](https://docs.github.com/en/pages/quickstart) for this but in all the examples I followed, they give the profile name to the repository name.

Ex: If the profile name is `x` repository name is `x.github.io`

Can't we give a different name for the repository?

Ex: If the profile name is `x` repository name is `x12.github.io`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use `indrajith.github.io` because `indrajith` is likely another GitHub user's name. So you cannot use other than your `<github user>.github.io`.

If you want to server your pages from `https://indrajith.github.io`, you have to rename your user name to `indrajith` if the username is available.

REF: [Changing your GitHub username](https://docs.github.com/en/account-and-profile/setting-up-and-managing-your-personal-account-on-github/managing-personal-account-settings/changing-your-github-username)

Comment: Thanks, @seenukrathi I also came to the same conclusion. But I have a question what if I change my GitHub username? Will it change my GitHub pages website URL?

Comment: @INDRAJITHEKANAYAKE I have tested the scenario where you changed your user name. in that case, you have to rename your repository also to `<new user name>.github.io`. Else the pages will be served under a subfolder. In other words, your repository should always starts with your current username.